# Jenkins during fetch ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm a beginner to using jenkins and I'm having a problem with jenkins fetching from our repo.
I'm getting a "The remote end hung up unexpectedly" error.

> 08:26:19 Fetching upstream changes from git@my.gitrepo.net:myFork/myBranch.git
>
> 08:26:19  > git --version # timeout=10
>
> 08:26:19 using GIT_SSH to set credentials Jenkins user at gitlab
>
> 08:26:19  > git fetch --tags --progress git@my.gitrepo.net:myFork/myBranch.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>
> 08:27:22 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>
> 08:27:22 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@my.gitrepo.net:myFork/myBranch.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
>
> 08:27:22 stdout:
>
> 08:27:22 stderr: ssh: connect to host my.gitrepo.net port 22: Connection timed out
>
> 08:27:22 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I thought that maybe the remote is unreachable but I tried using

> *git ls-remote (our_repo.git)*

in my local machine and it works so maybe it's not issue. (I guess?)

Is there configuration I need to consider to ensure the connection is correct? 
Like maybe proper SSH. Currently we have set public SSH though.

Comment: You must try the same command (ls-remote) from the slave machine where jenkins is cloning the repo

Comment: I checked it again today and the fetching finally works. Looks like some machine was just down for maintenance so that's our repo was not fetched.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it works from your local machine simply means your public ssh key (`$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`) is registered in GitLab.

As mentioned in the [GitLab-Jenkins integration page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html), you need to **[setup a deploy key](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys)**, and make sure it is deployed on the Git repo you want to access (see the settings of your GitLab project)